# How to create animation on the linestring with arrow sign?

Tags: openlayers, angular-openlayers

I'm able draw the linestring on the map based on the data but I want to draw the animated linestring as shown in attached image. Could anyone help me out for this from #openlayers community?

Inside myLayerFeature I have list of feature with its coordinates and looping through each feature to draw line and adding the gif image on that with taking reference of the following link:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

```
$(myLayerFeature).each((index, mapitem1) => {
                        moveArrowOnLine(mapitem1.geometry);
                    });
```

```
function moveArrowOnLine(geometry) {
                debugger
                var startCoordinates = geometry.coordinates[0];
                var endCoordinates = geometry.coordinates[1];


                const startMarker = new ol.Feature({
                    type: 'icon',
                    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(startCoordinates),
                });
                const endMarker = new ol.Feature({
                    type: 'icon',
                    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(endCoordinates),
                });
                const position = startMarker.getGeometry().clone();
                const geoMarker = new ol.Feature({
                    type: 'geoMarker',
                    geometry: position,
                });

                const styles = {
                    'route': new ol.style.Style({
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            width: 6,
                            color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8],
                        }),
                    }),
                    'geoMarker': new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon({
                            scale: -0.04,
                            anchor: [0, 0.8],
                            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                            anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                            opacity: 1,
                            projection: '3857',
                            src: './images/left-arrow.png',
                        }),
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({
                            radius: 20,
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'red' }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: 'black',
                                width: 2,
                            }),
                        }),
                    }),
                };

                const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: new ol.source.Vector({
                        features: [geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker],
                    }),
                    style: function (feature) {
                        return styles[feature.get('type')];
                    },
                });
                map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
                startAnimation();
            }
```

Comment: You need to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Start with an openlayers example, press edit on the upper right corner, fork it, insert your minimal code to reproduce the problem, and then edit your question to provide the link.

Comment: Hello https://stackexchange.com/users/11420690/mike